# select box inside a td

Tags: jquery, find

How can I check if there is a select box inside a td

```
if(there is select box inside td){
alert('yes');
}else{
alert('no');
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if ($('td select').length) { // or el.find('select').length; in case of cached selector
    alert('yes');
    $('td:has("select")').remove('select'); //to remove select
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I remove the select box if it is there?

Comment: @Dhar `$('td:has("select")').remove('select');`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if($('td select').length){
   //select exists
}
```